# jquery put a value instead of selector name

Tags: jquery, html

hello  this is how i usualy select an element to get it name

```
<div id="song-name"></div>

<a href="#" id="play">Play</a>
<a href="#" id="pause">Pause</a>
<a href="#" id="skip">next</a>
<a href="#" id="previous">previous</a>
<br><br>

  <audio  id="1"   name="song1" class="audio-player" src="music.mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="2" name="song2" class="audio-player" src="music2.mp3"></audio>



  var songName=$("1").attr("name");
```

but i need something like this

```
   var id=1;
        songName=$("id").attr("name");
```

what is write syntax for it?

i need that because i have this script that show current music playing name,but it only show the first song name even if next song is playing

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $(".audio-player").length;
    var z = 0;

    var songName=$("audio").attr("name");


    $("#play").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].play();
        $("#song-name").text(songName);
        $("#song-name").show();
    })
    $("#pause").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
        $("#song-name").hide();
    })
    $("#skip").click(function(){

        $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
        z++;
        if (z >= x) z = 0;


        $(".audio-player")[z].play();

        $(".audio-player")[z].currentTime = 0;
        $("#song-name").text(songName);
         $("#song-name").show();


    })




    $("#previous").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
        z=z-1;
        if (z >= x) z = 0;
        $(".audio-player")[z].play();
        $(".audio-player")[z].currentTime = 0;
        $("#song-name").text(songName);
    })
    });
    </Script>
```

so what i will do is edit #skip function

```
       $("#skip").click(function(){

            $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
    //where i edit       
    var  id=id+1;
        var songName=$("#id").attr("name");
//finish edit

            z++;
            if (z >= x) z = 0;


            $(".audio-player")[z].play();

            $(".audio-player")[z].currentTime = 0;
            $("#song-name").text(songName);
             $("#song-name").show();


        })
```

Comment: Class names, id are not supposed to start with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string concatenation with [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()):

```
var id = 1;
var songName = $("#" + id).attr("name"); // "#" + id => "#1"
```